# Creating an overlay network using ASA and VXLAN over IP MPLS

Tags: cisco, cisco-asa, mpls, vxlan

I need to extend an existing VLAN from a branch LAN to DC. As a matter of fact I noticed that Cisco ASA 5500X have VXLAN capabilities. I am relatively new to VXLAN and I need some help to find the best solution.[image: VXLAN configuration in ASDM]
My questions are: how can I use VXLAN to create an overlay across my ISP's IP MPLS network? should I use two identical ASAs? and is it possible to use our Cisco ACI  Fabric with an ASA to perform the required task?

Comment: Are you absolutely sure you need to extend the VLAN?  Are there other options?

Comment: No there are no other options, my client has no other alternatives, but it will serve for a PoC only, since in production we think about using an L2 fiber connection.

Comment: Extending layer-2 across a wide area is a really bad idea. We live in a layer-3 world, and everything can be routed.

Comment: I agree @RonMaupin, yet this doesn't solve my problem. We're working with some old devices that require this setup.

Comment: I looked into some other solutions such as :
- OTV, but it requires Nexus switches which do not exist in my branch setup
- L2TPv3, but it requires buying routers with Data + Security licenses
So actually, using VXLAN with ASA is the most economic solution for my PoC.

Comment: Obviously, your ISP already has an MPLS platform; so why not ask them if they have VPLS or EoMPLS  functionality in their portfolio, too?  Buying a L2 service from them might be less cumbersome, eventually.  Plus: With the SP providing the services on top of a network *they* have full control over, chances are hight that *you* won't fall into one of the L2-extension-over-L3-network-not-under-your-own-control traps.

Comment: VXLAN by its nature is rather an "intra datacenter" technology. The VXLAN header adds 50bytes to each packet/frame it transports, you'll need a underlay network that supports oversize packets/frames between VTEPs - else there won't be any support for full size frames/packets in the overlay.  You *might* make this work even if there's only 1500bytes of PathMTU from VTEP to VTEP --- if you are confident that you can adapt all "old devices" in the overlay network to use a lower default MTU.  But on that network map, I'd be sure to put a "here be dragons" warning.